# Print star pattern using equation of straight line

Tags: java

I want to print the following pattern:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I know the equation will be `x+y<=5`. For this equation we have to print `*`, but I can't get the `for` loop conditions.
Please help.
Edit: Here is the code I wrote:

```
public class Pattern{
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <=5; j++)
            System.out.print((-i+j)<=5 ? "*" : " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

The equation for the pattern in terms of a straight line in the 2nd quadrant will be y-x<=5. But the conditions in the for loop do not satisfy.

Comment: it can be a inner for loop e.g. `for (...) { for (...) ` - show us what you tried

Comment: We would like to see your work.

Comment: if x = 0, y = 0 is in the top left hand corner then the equation is `x + y >= 4` isn't it?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: You can check the Documentation on Basic Control Structures here; https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures#t=201706090836091564667. As this is really basic in any programming language, my advice is to take your time and read up on the topic.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I know the basic method to print a  star pattern using for loops but I was wondering if we can do this using equation of a straight line like the one I mentioned. We will have to use inequality to cover the entire area where * are present.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take advantage of [String formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to achieve this which is better than loop structures in this case. `%s` means 'print me this String value that I'm passing as an argument'. `%5s` means 'print me this String value that I'm passing, it should have a fixed length of 5 characters'.

```
 StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%5s", x.append("*").toString()));
 }
```

Or use `printf` instead of `String.format`. `\n` means Newline (`println` appends this single newline character automatically behind the curtains)

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
   System.out.printf("%5s\n", x.append("*").toString());
}
```

Comment: What if we have variable length pattern,i.e,size is not necessarily 5?

Comment: You cannot use variables in the expression, but you can however build the expression using string concatenation. E.g. `"%" + size + "s";`

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested loop solution, with 5 iterations.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
    {
     System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The first nested loop prints the spaces, with the spaces being `5 - iteration number`.
The second nested loop prints the `*`, the number of which is equal to the iteration number.

If you wish to run it `n` times, just replace `5` with `n`.

Also, there are many websites to help you with these, eg: [Print Star Pattern in Java](http://www.sitesbay.com/java-program/java-triangle-of-star)

Comment: You have used 3 for loops but if we use straight line equation we can print the pattern using only two loops. I can't seem to work out the conditions.

Comment: @RishabhKapri Are you sure? Then maybe you could specify the general method for using 2 loops.

Comment: Something like i+j<=5 (equation of a straight line)

Answer (score -1):

Code Explanation: Here we use println() function to print output, after print one output cursor move in new line. The main difference between print() and println() function is; print() function don't move cursor in new line after print output on screen but in case of println() function it move cursor in new line after print output.

This JAVA program is to print a pattern of right triangle using star(*).

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

**Logic**

We use a nested for loop which counts till the ith value and keeps printing a star till that value.

**Program**

```
import java.util.*;

 class sp2
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 { 
 int i,j,n;
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the number of rows");
     n = sc.nextInt();

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         for(j=i;j<n;j++)
         {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
         for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
         {
             System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println("");
     } 
 }
}
```

**Output**

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Comment: Does not look like pattern OP needs

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sorry for wrong pattern I updated my answer.